Pushing a ball to target position using direct method with contacts as LCP constraints
Sorry for the lengthy question!
I implemented such case that the end-effector pushes a ball to target position, as shown in the screenshot below. I did not use a gripper, instead welded a tiny sphere to link8 the arm as a dummy finger. Its frame is shown by the solid rgb triad. The transparent triad on the table top is the target position. Then the dummy finger is to push the ball to the target. Using a sphere make it much easier to define the contact point in ball frame when mapping the contact forces to generalized dofs.

The problem setup:

N = 150
duration = 2.
cost: squared error on balls position at tf, penalty on the slack variable and minimum torque over the entire trajectory
constraints: defects on v & q, LCP constraints with 2 contacts. One is dummy finger to ball, one is table to ball.

What I have tried:

free motion with panda arm only, only to move dummy finger to target location. very easy to get a solution.
tried solving with sliding contact with 6 basis vector in the contact tangent plane. Not getting a solution.
tried with only normal contact with no tangential components. Not getting a solution.
all solved with "good" initial guess by interpolation (it looked quite plausible to my eyes).
tried to penalize the distance between dummy finger to ball
tried to enforce dummy finger touching the ball at all time points as hard constraint.

I have been stucking at getting a solution for a while. Tried to visualize the trajectory without convergence, it looked very weird! Here just to post my problem and share some code snippets(only with normal contact for now). Any advice and help would be appreciated! Thank you very much!!!!!!!!
Here is the code for defects on v for the case with only normal contact force, which generally follows the implementation in drake's source code and integration of quaternion:
def Defects_v_ti(x_ti, contacts_in_body): 
    global nv, nq, nu, nContact
    assert x_ti.size == nv + nq + nv + nu + nContact*1,  "Input defects on v dim is wrong!"# last 1 for slack 

    v = x_ti[:nv]
    q_next = x_ti[nv: nv+nq]
    v_next = x_ti[nv+nq: nv+nq+nv]
    u_next = x_ti[nv+nq+nv: nv+nq+nv+nu]
    ee2ball_lambdaN = x_ti[nv+nq+nv+nu]
    env2ball_lambdaN = x_ti[nv+nq+nv+nu+1]

    if x_ti.dtype == object:
        plant_eval = plant_AD
        context_eval = mutable_plant_context_AD
        context_eval_next = mutable_plant_context_AD_next
        panda_model_instance = plant_eval.GetModelInstanceByName("panda")
        ball_model_instance = plant_eval.GetModelInstanceByName("000_my_sphere")
        nv = plant_eval.num_velocities(panda_model_instance) + plant_eval.num_velocities(ball_model_instance)
        y = np.array([AutoDiffXd(0)]*nv)
        u_next_all_dofs = np.array([AutoDiffXd(0)]*nv)
        f_ball2dummy_w_6D = np.array([AutoDiffXd(0)]*6)
        f_table2ball_w_6D = np.array([AutoDiffXd(0)]*6)

        if not AutoDiffArrayEqual(v, plant_eval.GetVelocities(context_eval)):
            plant_eval.SetVelocities(context_eval, v)
        if not AutoDiffArrayEqual(q_next, plant_eval.GetPositions(context_eval_next)):
            plant_eval.SetPositions(context_eval_next, q_next)
        if not AutoDiffArrayEqual(v_next, plant_eval.GetVelocities(context_eval_next)):
            plant_eval.SetVelocities(context_eval_next, v_next)

    else:
        plant_eval = plant_double
        context_eval = mutable_plant_context_double
        context_eval_next = mutable_plant_context_double_next
        panda_model_instance = plant_eval.GetModelInstanceByName("panda")
        ball_model_instance = plant_eval.GetModelInstanceByName("000_my_sphere")
        nv = plant_eval.num_velocities(panda_model_instance) + plant_eval.num_velocities(ball_model_instance)
        y = np.zeros(nv)
        u_next_all_dofs = np.zeros(nv)
        f_ball2dummy_w_6D = np.zeros(6)
        f_table2ball_w_6D = np.zeros(6)
        
        if not np.array_equal(v, plant_eval.GetVelocities(context_eval)):
            plant_eval.SetVelocities(context_eval, v)
        if not np.array_equal(q_next, plant_eval.GetPositions(context_eval_next)):
            plant_eval.SetPositions(context_eval_next, q_next)
        if not np.array_equal(v_next, plant_eval.GetVelocities(context_eval_next)):
            plant_eval.SetVelocities(context_eval_next, v_next)
    
    ball_frame = plant_eval.GetFrameByName("ball_base_link")
    dummy_finger_frame = plant_eval.GetFrameByName("dummy1")
    dummy_finger_pose_in_w_next = dummy_finger_frame.CalcPoseInWorld(context_eval_next)

    # the actuation term
    u_next_all_dofs[-7:] = u_next
    y += u_next_all_dofs

    """ Mapping all contact forces into generalized cooridinates """
    # 1. ball contact force to arm
    # compute nhat_in_w
    ball_pose_w_next = ball_frame.CalcPoseInWorld(context_eval_next)
    ball_pos_w_next = ball_pose_w_next.translation()
    dummy_pos_w_next = dummy_finger_pose_in_w_next.translation()
    nhat_ball2dummy_w = (ball_pos_w_next - dummy_pos_w_next)/np.linalg.norm(ball_pos_w_next - dummy_pos_w_next)

    f_ball2dummy_w = nhat_ball2dummy_w * ee2ball_lambdaN
    f_ball2dummy_w_6D[-3:] = f_ball2dummy_w
    
    J_next = plant_eval.CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity(context_eval_next,
                                               JacobianWrtVariable.kV,
                                               plant_eval.GetFrameByName("dummy1"),
                                               np.array([0., 0., 0.]),
                                               plant_eval.world_frame(),
                                               plant_eval.world_frame())
    y += J_next.T @ f_ball2dummy_w_6D

    # 2. the same contact force to ball
    # Compute points:
    T_obj_hand_next = dummy_finger_frame.CalcPose(context_eval_next, ball_frame)
    p_BCb = np.array([0., 0., 0.])
    p_ACa = ComputePointOnSphereSurface_UsingFrame(T_obj_hand_next, p_BCb, radius=0.04)
    J_next = plant_eval.CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity(context_eval_next,
                                               JacobianWrtVariable.kV,
                                               plant_eval.GetFrameByName("ball_base_link"),
                                               p_ACa,
                                               plant_eval.world_frame(),
                                               plant_eval.world_frame())
    # Newton's 3rd law
    f_dummy2ball_w_6D = -f_ball2dummy_w_6D
    y += J_next.T @ f_dummy2ball_w_6D 

    # 3. table contact force to ball
    nhat_table2ball_w = np.array([0., 0., 1.])
    f_table2ball_w = nhat_table2ball_w * env2ball_lambdaN
    f_table2ball_w_6D[-3:] = f_table2ball_w

    direction = np.array([0., 0., -1.]) # the contact point vector is always downward in {w}
    p_ACa = ComputePointOnSphereSurface_UsingDirection(ball_pose_w_next.rotation(), direction, radius=0.04)
    J_next = plant_eval.CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity(context_eval_next,
                                               JacobianWrtVariable.kV,
                                               plant_eval.GetFrameByName("ball_base_link"),
                                               p_ACa,
                                               plant_eval.world_frame(),
                                               plant_eval.world_frame())
    y += J_next.T @ f_table2ball_w_6D

    # C term
    c_next = plant_eval.CalcBiasTerm(context_eval_next)
    y -= c_next

    # G term
    g_next = plant_eval.CalcGravityGeneralizedForces(context_eval_next)
    y += g_next
    
    # acceleration term 
    M_next = plant_eval.CalcMassMatrixViaInverseDynamics(context_eval_next)

    y = M_next @ (v_next - v) - y * h

    return y

Here is the snippet for defects on q:
def Defects_q_ti(x_ti, h):
    """
    implements integration of quaternion by Implicit Euler
    x_ti: (q, q_next, v_next)

    # position indexing in Drake: w,thetax,thetay,thetaz, x,y,z
    """
    q = x_ti[:nq]
    q_next = x_ti[nq:nq+nq]
    v_next = x_ti[nq+nq:]

    q_ball = q[nq_arm:]
    q_ball_next = q_next[nq_arm:]
    v_ball_next = v_next[nv_arm:]

    if x_ti.dtype == object:
        y = np.array([AutoDiffXd(0)]*nq)
        plant_eval = plant_AD
        context_eval = mutable_plant_context_AD
        context_eval_next = mutable_plant_context_AD_next
        if not AutoDiffArrayEqual(q, plant_eval.GetPositions(context_eval)):
            plant_eval.SetPositions(context_eval, q)
        if not AutoDiffArrayEqual(q_next, plant_eval.GetPositions(context_eval_next)):
            plant_eval.SetPositions(context_eval_next, q_next)
        if not AutoDiffArrayEqual(v_next, plant_eval.GetVelocities(context_eval_next)):
            plant_eval.SetVelocities(context_eval_next, v_next)
    else:
        y = np.zeros(nq)
        plant_eval = plant_double
        context_eval = mutable_plant_context_double
        context_eval_next = mutable_plant_context_double_next
        if not np.array_equal(q, plant_eval.GetPositions(context_eval)):
            plant_eval.SetPositions(context_eval, q)
        if not np.array_equal(q_next, plant_eval.GetPositions(context_eval_next)):
            plant_eval.SetPositions(context_eval_next, q_next)
        if not np.array_equal(v_next, plant_eval.GetVelocities(context_eval_next)):
            plant_eval.SetVelocities(context_eval_next, v_next)

    # get angular velocity for quaternion integration
    ball_frame = plant_eval.GetFrameByName("ball_base_link")
    ball_angular_v_next = ball_frame.EvalAngularVelocityInWorld(context_eval_next)

    # add conditionals, if v or v_next are zeros or close to zeros, then set all zeros
    if ball_angular_v_next[0]**2 + ball_angular_v_next[1]**2 + ball_angular_v_next[2]**2 < 0.0001:
        ball_w_mag_next = 0.
        ball_w_axis_next = np.array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=x_ti.dtype)
    else:
        ball_w_mag_next = np.sqrt(ball_angular_v_next[0]**2 + ball_angular_v_next[1]**2 + ball_angular_v_next[2]**2)
        ball_w_axis_next = ball_angular_v_next / ball_w_mag_next

    # enforce the defects for the ball
    v_ball_next_trans = v_ball_next[-3:]
    q_ball_pos = q_ball[-3:]
    q_ball_quat = q_ball[:4]
    q_ball_pos_next = q_ball_next[-3:]

    y[4:7] = q_ball_pos_next - q_ball_pos - h*v_ball_next_trans # implicit-euler on position updates
    ball_q_x_deltaq = ApplyAngularVelocityToQuaternion(q_ball_quat, ball_w_axis_next, ball_w_mag_next, h)
    y[:4] = ball_q_x_deltaq - q_ball_quat # implicit-euler on orientation

    # enforce the defects for the arm
    q_arm = q[:nq_arm]
    q_arm_next = q[:nq_arm]
    v_next_arm = v_next[:nv_arm]
    y[7:] = q_arm_next - q_arm - h*v_next_arm   
    return y

Here is the signed distance part for the LCP constraints:
def LCP_G_ti(x_ti, contacts_list, radius=0.04):
    nContact = len(contacts_list)
    num_constraints = nContact * 1 
    q = x_ti[:nq]
    v = x_ti[nq:]

    if x_ti.dtype == object:
        plant_eval = plant_AD
        context_eval = mutable_plant_context_AD
        y = np.array([AutoDiffXd(0)]*num_constraints)
        if not AutoDiffArrayEqual(q, plant_eval.GetPositions(context_eval)):
            plant_eval.SetPositions(context_eval, q)
        if not AutoDiffArrayEqual(v, plant_eval.GetVelocities(context_eval)):
            plant_eval.SetVelocities(context_eval, v)
    else:
        plant_eval = plant_double
        context_eval = mutable_plant_context_double
        y = np.zeros(num_constraints)
        if not np.array_equal(q, plant_eval.GetPositions(context_eval)):
            plant_eval.SetPositions(context_eval, q)
        if not np.array_equal(v, plant_eval.GetVelocities(context_eval)):
            plant_eval.SetVelocities(context_eval, v)
    
    # Part 1: hand and ball contact
    dummy1_frame = plant_eval.GetFrameByName("dummy1")
    ball_frame = plant_eval.GetFrameByName("ball_base_link")
    ball_pose_in_world = ball_frame.CalcPoseInWorld(context_eval)
    
    # 1 entry for distance in {body}
    dummy1_pos_in_ball = dummy1_frame.CalcPose(context_eval, ball_frame).translation()
    distance = np.sqrt(dummy1_pos_in_ball[0]**2 + dummy1_pos_in_ball[1]**2 + dummy1_pos_in_ball[2]**2)
    y[0] = distance - radius
   
    ball_pos_in_w = ball_pose_in_world.translation()
    y[1] = np.dot(ball_pos_in_w, np.array([0., 0., 1.])) - radius

    return y

Here is the snippet for the equality part of the LCP constraint:
def LCP_G_times_H_WithSlack_ti(x_ti, processed_contacts_list):
    global nv, nq
    nContact = len(processed_contacts_list)
    q = x_ti[:nq]
    v = x_ti[nq: nq+nv]
    lambdas = x_ti[nq+nv: nq+nv+nContact]
    slack = x_ti[-1]
    
    H = lambdas
    x_in = np.concatenate((q, v))
    # the entries of H must be consistent with G
    G = LCP_G_ti(x_in, processed_contacts_list)
    return np.array([slack - np.dot(G, H)]) # dot product, NOT element-wise


The LCP constraints are difficult constraints for SNOPT to solve directly. Typically, one needs to solve a relaxed version (e.g. x perp f as x * f = 0 => x * f <= epsilon).  There's a discussion, e.g. in 3.2 of Posa13
